# Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: interval near line

Tags: java, scala, hibernate, spring-data

@Query("SELECT sr FROM SignedReceipt sr where sr.cashBox_id=:rk and sr.since between :from and date_add(:from,interval 1 DAY) order by sr.since limit 1")

def findFirstSingnedReceiptByFrom(@Param("rk") rk: CashRegister,@Param("from")from:DateTime)

Comment: I am affraid `def` does not work in java.

Comment: it works in scala

Comment: it s not java it s scala

Comment: the mistake is in request

Answer (score 0):

replace date_add(:from,interval 1 DAY) with adddate(:from ,1)